# Best practice to handle a MySQL connection in a long running python script

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, pymysql

I currently have a long running python script (multiple days), which occasionally executes queries in a mysql db. The queries are executed from different threads.

I connect to the db as following:

```
import mysql.connector
import time

class DB():
    connection = None

    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database):
        self.host = host;
        self.user = user;
        self.password = password;
        self.database = database;

    self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.connection =  mysql.connector.connect(
                host = self.host,
                user = self.user,
                password = self.password,
                database = self.database,
                autocommit = True,
            )
        except Exception as exception:
            print("[DBCONNECTION] {exception} Retrying in 5 seconds.".format(exception = str(exception)))
            time.sleep(5)
            self.connect()

db = DB("11.111.11.111", "mydb", "mydb", "mydb")
```

One of the functions to execute a query:

```
def getUsersDB(self):
    db.connection.ping(reconnect=True)

    cursor = db.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")
    
    users = cursor.fetchall()

    return users
```

I believe, that I'm far away from a good practice how I handle the connection. What is the correct way for such a case?

Comment: Why do you believe this is not a good practice?

Comment: My approach is pretty much guessed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that `db.connection.ping(reconnect=True)` doesn't promise you a live connection.

You can read the function's description here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-ping.html

You can try to use this:

```
class DB:
    connection = None

    def __init__(
        self,
        host: str,
        user: str,
        password: str,
        database: str
    ) -> None:
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.database = database

        self.connection = self.init_conn()

    def init_conn(
        self,
    ):
        return mysql.connector.connect(
            host=self.host,
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password,
            database=self.database,
        )

    def get_cursor(
        self,
    ):
        # This will try to reconnect also.
        # In case it fails, you will have to create a new connection
        try:
            self.connection.ping(
                reconnect=True,
                attempts=3,
                delay=5,
            )
        except mysql.connector.InterfaceError as err:
            self.connection = self.init_conn()

        return self.connection.cursor()
```

And use the `DB` object like this:

```
def getUsersDB(self):
    cursor = db.get_cursor() # cursor from a live connection 

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")
    
    users = cursor.fetchall()

    return users
```